# Infopath Publishing Issues

Tags: infopath, central-administration

I published an Infopath 2007 form with custom code(which have no errors) on central admin like one day back and till now it shows its status as “upgrading” on central admin.

1. I don’t know like why it’s taking so long time ?
2. Although its status is Upgrading on central admin but I found that form on production site but when you open it, its giving some error like
   There has been an error while processing the form.
   Click Continue to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.
   Click Start Over to load a new copy of the form.
   Error Details :
   “An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5337 ”

when I enter into the Event log on that server I was not able to find an event with id 5337.
can you please suggest me what to do to remove the error .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Restart timer service (net stop SPTimerV3 / net start SPTimerV3)
- Run "stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs"
- Remove and add the form again

Comment: yes It's working fine.... After restarted the following services. 1. SPAdminV4
2. SPTimerV4 Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In Services.msc, check for the SharePoint timer job. Check if the login credentials are proper in it. Restart the Timer service and then refresh the Manage forms page.

Hope this helps.